# npm start not running in PowerShell

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using react.js with create-react-app. my problem is when executed `npm start` in bash shell everything all right but npm start executed in PowerShell, the following error is displayed on the screen

```
.../client-webapp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: node: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! client-webapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client-webapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\r-rajaee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-20T12_13_45_841Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Just let me know can you call command **node** in your PowerShell console?
I assume you cant and you are using windows so you have to just uinstall node, and install again but during instalation enable PATH option to autmatically add node to your PATH collection. After that restart console and try again. It should use node installed globally but path does not exist for Powershell so it looks node in node_modules..

Comment: Yes. I can call node command in my PowerShell. I uninstall node.js and reinstalled it. but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use **sudo npm start** or give admin permissions to the folder, I hope it works for you